# View Dependencies misses calls to some three-part names in a stored procedure. Is this normal?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dependencies, ssms, truncate

I've inherited a stored procedure. It begins like this.

```sql
USE [DBFOO]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Bar]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TODAY DATETIME = GETDATE()

BEGIN
TRUNCATE TABLE [DBFOO].[dbo].[MyTable1]
TRUNCATE TABLE [DBFOO].[dbo].[MyTable2]

INSERT INTO [DBFOO].[dbo].[MyTable1]
[...]

INSERT INTO [DBFOO].[dbo].[MyTable2]
[...]


END
END
```

when I check SSMS's View Dependencies menu for this procedure and for `MyTable1`, the dependency on this table in this procedure is not listed. However, `MyTable2` is.

Is this normal behaviour? If so, then what exactly is causing this table to not be detected and how can I detect dependencies that are like this?

Comment: So, just to make sure, the procedure `TRUNCATE`s the table, but then never repopulates it? That, I must admit, seems a little odd.

Comment: @ThomA Actually, the insert into repopulates it. I best make that explicit. Thanks for pointing it out. I've also retitled the question.

Comment: what happens when you create a copy of procedure, does the dep look the same for the copy?

Comment: @siggemannen Yes. Identical.

Comment: What does this outputs: select object_name(referenced_id), object_name(referencing_id), *
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies

Comment: @siggemannen The missing table appears for both the original procedure and the copy. Fascinating!

Comment: I don't know what "View Dependencies" does exactly, but maybe it sucks? :) The table i mention is the modern way of tracking dependencies.

Comment: @siggemannen As far as I knew, View Dependencies calls what you've told me to call.

Comment: @siggemannen `TRUNCATE` does not appear in `sql_expression_dependencies`, so if there is no `INSERT` that may be the cause. https://dbfiddle.uk/AS450cam

Comment: @Charlieface Adding the `INSERT` doesn't seem to add it in either. https://dbfiddle.uk/BU49TFuA

Comment: I can't recreate the issue on my old sql server 2014

Comment: maybe something with the fiddle rights, i don't know

Comment: anyways, this can happen if table is created after procedure is. I never trust dependencies anyway because at least everywhere i worked, people (ab)used dynamic sql which makes it unreliable

Comment: @siggemannen So how do you detect dependencies?

Comment: You don't, like the saying goes, if you need to ask, you can't afford it. Why do you need to know the deps?

Comment: @siggemannen I think you've given me all of the help that I'm going to get. Thank you.